# Solution range for an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given $a\in(\frac{1}2,1)$ such that $$0<(1-a)<\frac{1}2<1<\frac{3}2<(1+a)<2,$$ is there an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $$0<(1-a)<\frac{1}2<(1-a)x<1<\frac{(1+a)}x<\frac{3}2<(1+a)<2?$$

What is range of $x\in\Bbb R$?

For which $a\in(\frac{1}2,1)$ does such a range of $x\in\Bbb R$ exist?

Comment: I suggest you split the expression into four different inequalities for $x$. That is easy to do. Next you can examine how $x$ and $a$ are interrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{2}<(1-a)x<1$ and $1-a>0$, we get $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2(1-a)}<x<\frac{1}{1-a}$.

Since $\displaystyle 1<\frac{1+a}{x}<\frac{3}{2}$ and $x>0$, $\;\;\;x<1+a\;$ and $\;1+a<\frac{3}{2}x\;\;$ so $\displaystyle\;\;\frac{2}{3}(1+a)<x<1+a$.

---

If $\displaystyle 1+a\le\frac{1}{2(x-a)}$, then there is no solution; and
$\displaystyle 1+a\le\frac{1}{2(x-a)}\iff1-a^2\le\frac{1}{2}\iff a^2\ge\frac{1}{2}$,

so there is no solution if $a\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

---

$\displaystyle\frac{2}{3}(1+a)<\frac{1}{2(1-a)}\iff\frac{4}{3}(1-a^2)<1\iff1-a^2<\frac{3}{4}\iff a^2>\frac{1}{4}$, which holds for $a>\frac{1}{2}$;

so since $1+a<\frac{1}{1-a}$, the inequality is satisfied for $\displaystyle x\in\left(\frac{1}{2(1-a)},1+a\right)$ when $a\in\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.